# Removing the frame line from the geom_violin() function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

Does anyone know how I can remove the curved frame line and only leave the dots in the violin plot when using geom_violin function? As shown in the graph below

[image: 1https://i.stack.imgur.com/axlVw.png]

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd want to use the violin plot to produce a dot plot? You could just use geom_dotplot to get what you need.

Comment: I don't get dots with `geom_violin`; e.g. ```ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), drat)) +
  geom_violin()```

Answer (score 1):

first I think that doesn't make sense you remove the shape because it is really helpfull to visualize the distribution of the variable.

But, if you really want it, you have to use `geom_dotplot()` insted of `geom_violin()`.

Your code could be like this:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), drat)) +
    geom_dotplot(binaxis ="y", stackdir = "center")
```

Then, your result is gonna be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am curious how did you get the flower shape of dots? I try to change it to square but didn't know how

Comment: @aHI that's just rendering. It's not "flower shaped" it's still a circle, just rendered poorly and seen as whatever that you called it :D